# custom syntax hilighting lost on single LaTeX file

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

I use **vimtex** plugin for writing tex documents in **vim8**. I added custom hilight for sections in my .vimrc like so:

```
autocmd FileType tex :syntax match texSectioning "\\section.*"
```

The `texSectioning` is defined in my color scheme file in `.vim/colors`.

It works on any file with `.tex` extension except for one! Copying/movig the file to different dir or/and changing name, changing file extention to `.txt` and then manually switching on tex filetype does not help. Even typing

```
syntax match texSectioning "\\section.*"
```

command has no effect.  There is no `.swp` file, I didn't use `mkview` (there is no `view` folder in .vim), I didn't use sessions.

I'm really confused by this...

**Edit:**

the output of `set filetype` is `filetype=tex`. The standard syntax highlighting works, I'm only missing he custom one.

Apparently, removing `.latexmkrc` **solved** the problem.
 There must have been some interference between `vimtex` and `latexmk`, but it is wierd if that was the case...

Comment: Check the output of `set filetype` in that file. If it is 'plaintex', then you should add `let g:tex_flavor = 'latex'` in your vimrc file.